# C++ and SQL server Job is it possible ? how ?

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008, visual-c++

i am trying to write a function which can Add some Jobs  into SQL server 2008 Agent 
how can i do it ? there is something about SMO and DMO ? DMO removed for sql server 2008 and i can use SMO in C++ or i should be in C++ manage ? 
Could you please help me ! sample code would be appreciate  :)
tanks

Comment: i did it with script . Sql server Create Jobs whit script  . i get that script and put it in my source code and execute that script from c++ , just this :)

Answer (score 2):

yo can use T-SQL to create the jobs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182079.aspx)
sp_add_job (then steps and schedule) which you can call from C++...